# Zip files older than 30 days using 7zip

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

I know this question has been asked several times but my requirement is slightly different from what I have read here and on google.

I have the below folder structure.

```
c:\weblogs\Servers\Server1
c:\weblogs\Servers\Server2
```

Server 1 folder may contain folders such as:

```
W3SVC1
W3SVC2
W3SVC3
```

Server 2 would have a similar folder structure.

I am trying to create a script which would look at every `W3SVC*` folder for `.log` files older than 30 days.

It would then create a zip file called `Oldlogs-Server*-W3SVC*.zip` within each such `W3SVC*` subfolder and move the older logs to that file. On the second run it would simply move any new files older than 30 days to the respective zip file.

I am not a developer but any examples or suggestions would be helpful if there is not an existing script available.

This is the script which I believe comes closest to what I am trying to achieve:

It currently throws an error:

> "\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe needed"

```
# Alias for pkzip
if (-not (test-path "$env:F:\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe")) {
    throw "$env:F:\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe needed"
} 
set-alias sz "$env:WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe" 

############################################ 
#### Variables  

$filePath = "F:\Weblogs\Test" 

$log = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".log" } 

########### END of VARABLES ################## 

foreach ($file in $log) { 
    $name = $file.name 
    $directory = $file.DirectoryName 
    $zipfile = $name.Replace(".log",".7z") 
    sz a -t7z "$directory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"      
} 

########### END OF SCRIPT ##########
```

Comment: Kev, i have added the script that i did try to the question, I think it comes close to what i am trying to do . .

Answer (score 0):

> ```psh
> if (-not (test-path "$env:F:\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe")) {
>     throw "$env:F:\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe needed"
> } 
> set-alias sz "$env:WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe"
> ```

You're testing a path `$env:F:\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe`, which evaluates to `\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe`, since you probably don't have an environment variable `$env:F`. Because of that your script is looking for the executable on the current drive, which most likely is `C:` rather than `F:`. This is what causes the error you observed.

The next statement tries to set an alias `$env:WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe`. If you actually have an environment variable `$env:WebApps` change your code to this:

```psh
$pkzip = "$env:WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe"
if (-not (Test-Path $pkzip)) {
    throw "$pkzip needed"
} 
Set-Alias sz $pkzip
```

If you don't have that environment variable change your code to this:

```psh
$pkzip = "F:\WebApps\LogHarvest\pkzipc.exe"
if (-not (Test-Path $pkzip)) {
    throw "$pkzip needed"
} 
Set-Alias sz $pkzip
```

As a side note: instead of creating an alias for your script I'd use the variable for the executable with the call operator (`&`):

```psh
& $pkzip a -t7z "$directory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"
```

Also, I'm not sure if `pkzipc` can actually handle 7z archives. Or if it supports the arguments `a -t7z` in the first place. Those look like arguments for the 7zip programs to me.